# Is a database trigger slower than a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle, postgresql

I wonder if a trigger that executes an update after each insert in a table is slower than doing an update query manually after an insert query.

Comment: It depends on how you write the trigger. I could certainly imagine a trigger someone else might write that is much less efficient than a better query (doesn't really matter if it's explicitly in a trigger or not).

Comment: Also, since trigger functionality varies wildly from platform to platform, consider asking a question that targets the platform you're concerned about, instead of an all-encompassing, platform-agnostic one.

Answer (score 4):

As far as **PostgreSQL** is concerned:

For inserting / updating one row at a time, *hardly*. Although - not necessarily because of network overhead as argued by @Michael - you can pack `INSERT` *and* `UPDATE` into a single query. Consider [writeable CTEs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING).

For inserting / updating multiple or many rows at a time, *YES*, it *can* be considerably slower. Processing many rows in a single command is considerably cheaper, so one UPDATE for x rows would be much cheaper than x individual updates initiated by triggers.

Nothing can be said for certain, though, because many other factors play a role.

I am quoting [the manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/trigger-definition.html):

> PostgreSQL offers both per-row triggers and per-statement triggers.
>   With a per-row trigger, **the trigger function is invoked once for each
>   row that is affected** by the statement that fired the trigger.

Bold emphasis mine.

Comment: Doesn't this make the assumption that a trigger is written to handle a multi-row update row-by-row? Surely you can write a trigger that does a set-based operation with the same efficiency as the same query run manually outside the scope of a trigger.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: It does. And the assumption should be correct AFAIU. The effects of *all* triggers fired by one row are visible to the triggers fired by the next row. That's one of the reasons why RULEs can perform faster for bulk operations.  You can invoke a triggers *for each statement*, too. But that's no good for cascading updates. I added a quote from the manual.

Comment: Depends on the platform. Not all systems fire triggers per affected row (or even allow you to do that). In SQL Server you'd have to go out of your way to cause this "considerable" performance difference. Not that it doesn't stop people, nor does that make it easy to answer such a broad question that is supposed to cover many platforms. *shrug*

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I clarified this concerns PostgreSQL. I had missed that the OP tagged multiple RDBMS.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on a variety of factors.  In the first place, you've tagged this for three completely different database products.  The answer could be different for all three.

Considering just Oracle, it depends on things like how many rows you are impacting and whether this is the only trigger on the table.  If your `INSERT` statement inserts thousands of rows and this would be the only trigger on the table, creating the trigger forces thousands of SQL to PL/SQL context shifts and forces thousands of `UPDATE` statements to be run.  If you did a single `INSERT` into a table with no triggers followed by a single `UPDATE`, you would eliminate the need to do all those context shifts and your `UPDATE` statement might be able to use a plan that was more suitable for modifying thousands of rows rather than just one row.  If, on the other hand, your `INSERT` statement is inserting a single row, the performance difference are likely to be minimal since you'd prefer the single-row plan for the `UPDATE` statement and you'd only be doing one set of context shifts.

Of course, from an architecture standpoint, there may be other issues.  Updating table B from a row-level trigger on A is generally hard to do correctly in a multi-user environment.  Having a lot of such logic bound up in triggers tends to make systems very unstable-- it makes it hard for a developer to walk through the code to grasp the impacts of a change which frequently leads to mysterious bugs and inconsistencies.  It also frequently leads to situations where you have a long chain of inserts and updates generated by a series of triggers that eventually cause mutating table exceptions because an insert on table A modifies B which modifies C where you have a trigger that turns around and queries A.  If you need to maintain some sort of summary value (i.e. you're trying to update the `order_total` column of the `orders` table when someone modifies a row in `order_items`), a materialized view may be a more appropriate architectural solution.  Or you might be better served by a virtual column in the table or a view with a calculation.

Comment: +1, fantastic answer! Great observations. And if I wasn't doing all this from my phone I might say more. 

Comment: I want a "follow" button to see the answers of certain SO members from my homepage every day...

Comment: @Sebas [nah, it'll never happen](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84007/add-feature-favorite-users).

Comment: @Sebas: But if you're a true afficionado, make [his "recent answers" page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/10397/justin-cave?tab=answers) your homepage. ;)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, fantastic :-)

Comment: @Sebas: Not pun intended at all, huh? :)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter no, that was sincere :-) I got it in my fav now ;)

Answer (score 1):

In short it couldn't be because the execution plan of the trigger is compiled. Further, it's native to the statement so there is no network latency surrounding sending the statement.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complicated question and the answer is likely to depend on the database.

In general, I would expect a trigger to be at least as fast as doing a separate update when only one row is involved.  However, the situation might be different when multiple rows are being inserted.  In this case, some databases call the trigger once with multiple rows.  Some databases call the trigger multiple times, once for each row.

In the latter case, you might be able to have faster code by doing multiple operations at the same time.

Another consideration is throughput.  The operation with the trigger might be faster.  However, it might also lock the table or rows for a longer period of time, preventing other actions on the table.  You might find that interleaved database calls are faster than longer ones.

If you are asking such a question, my suggestion is that you do timings.  Do not expect the results to be the same for different databases.  Although database engines have a lot in common, this is dealing with details on locking and transactions, which do differ among the vendors.